# R fedmatch and multivariable

Tags: r

I am trying to use fedmatch to merge to datasets based on name and state columns using the multivar approach. I am getting an error message that I do not understand.

Here is my code

```
library(fedmatch)
library(haven)
library(tidyverse)

dfA <- read_csv("all_reference_usa.csv")
dfB <-read_csv("oc_sample.csv")

matches <- merge_plus(data1 = dfA, 
                      data2 = dfB,
                      match_type = "multivar", 
                      by = c("name", "state"),
                      unique_key_1 = "id", 
                      unique_key_2 = "company_number", 
                      multivar_settings = build_multivar_settings(
                        compare_type = c("stringdist", "stringdist"), 
                        wgts = c(.5, .5), nthread =1 
                      ))
```

here is the error message

```
Error in `[.data.table`(df_c, order(-multivar_score), utils::head(.SD,  : 
  column or expression 1 of 'by' or 'keyby' is type closure. Do not quote column names. Usage: DT[,sum(colC),by=list(colA,month(colB))]
```